# How to detect only external-module calls?

Tags: ida, disassembly, debugging, libraries

I'm debugging one module which draws some letters using either GDI or most possibly Direct Draw. I want to trace where this happens so for the reason I need to trace only instances of code, which doesn't belong to the current module. How is this possible?

I'm using IDA Pro 6.5 on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) for this. You can limit its trace to only display calls to GDI functions and DirectDraw functions:

[image: API Capture Filter]

[image: API Monitor]