# OllyDbg: how to record all funtion calls for attached process

Tags: ollydbg, debugging

I am trying to learn how IIS 5.0(running on Win2K Server) works with OllyDbg v1.10.
I attach Olly to inetinfo.exe, which is the process for IIS 5.0. Olly then pauses in ntdll. See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF79J.jpg).
My plan is: I send a request to IIS, then observe what functions are called. So I know how IIS handles a request. But I dont want to do it manually. Is there anyway to record function calls for a attached process?

OS: Win2K SP1

Comment: See [How to detect only external-module calls?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/how-to-detect-only-external-module-calls)

Comment: @JasonGeffner Thx very much for the tool. But it could not be installed on Win2K SP1....

Comment: According to http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor#Requirements it should work. If not, I'd recommend you email the author.

Answer (score 1):

ollydbg version 2.01

```
c:\> ollydbg calc

alt + e (executable modules)
ctrl+ p (set protocol)
select radio button call destination first 
then select add range 
in the start enter (alt+e-> your Module base)
int the end enter (alt+e -> Your module base + size)
```

[image]

and start tracing with ctrl+f11 (trace in ) 
ollydbg should show you all the calls like this

result

```
main calc.__security_init_cookie
main calc._SEH_prolog4
main calc._initterm_e
main calc.000B3942
main calc._get_image_app_type
main calc.RtlpImageNtHeader
main calc._SEH_prolog4
main calc._SEH_epilog4
main calc.CCalculatorDialog::GetDlgProc
main calc._setdefaultprecision
main calc.__CxxSetUnhandledExceptionFilter
main calc.CScaledResourceFactory::_LoadUsingWIC
main calc.CreateDecoderFromResource
main calc.FindRawResource
main calc.CScaledResourceFactory::_SelectFrameByDPI
main calc.CScaledResourceFactory::_ScaleSource
main calc.GetPixelFormatInfo
main calc.WICFormatToBpp
main calc.__security_check_cookie
main calc.WICBitmapToHBITMAP
main calc.GetPixelFormatInfo
main calc.WICFormatToBpp
main calc.__security_check_cookie
main calc.CreateHBITMAP
main calc.CScaledResourceFactory::Release
main calc.CScaledResourceFactory::`scalar
main calc.CScaledResourceFactory::~CScaledResourceFactory
main calc.operator
main calc.CCalcHelper::LoadImageScaledX
main calc.LoadImageScaled
main calc.CScaledResourceFactory::s_CreateInstance
main calc.operator
```